# Contar linhas e palavras de um ficheiro de texto em C

Tags: c, contador

Tenho um problema no projeto, este código deveria contar as linhas e as palavras de um ficheiro de texto em C mas o output do nº de linhas está certo e o nº de palavras é sempre 0.

```
//Função que conta as palavras de uma linha

int palavras(char *line)
{
  int p = 0, j;
  char *str = "\t\r\n\v\f";
  char *saveptr1, *str1, *token;

  line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';

  for (j = 1, str = line; j++, str1 = NULL ;)
  {
    token = strtok_r(str1, str, &saveptr1);

    if (token==NULL) break;
    p++;
  }

  return p;
}

// Resto do programa
int palavras(char[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  FILE * fp;
  ssize_t n = 0;

  int nlinhas = 0, p = 0;
  char * line = NULL;

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  exit_on_null(fp, "Erro na abertura");

  while ((n = getline(&line, &n, fp)) != -1)
  {
    line[strlen(line) - 1]='\0'; /

    p = palavras(line);
    nlinhas++;
  }

  printf("Número de Linhas: %i\n",nlinhas);
  printf("Número de Palavras: %i\n",p);

  if (line) free(line);

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dê uma revisada nes te comando: `for(j=1,str=line;j++,str1=NULL;)` pois você colocou o incremento junto com a condição de término do loop. Também me parece que você misturou o uso de str e str1 já que você inicializa str com os caracteres separadores (faltou o espaço) mas aponta para a string recebida por parâmetro.

Comment: O problema é que quando compilo o código me diz que é expectado um ; antes do token ) assim: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token for(j=1,str1=line;j++,str1=NULL) e não percebo porque dá esse erro.

Comment: Reveja seu comando for, ele não faz sentido. Qual o motivo destas atribuições?

Comment: Eu quero que passe por cada linha (sendo o j o nº de linhas) e que use a string que vem do line e depois usando a função strtok_r ver se conta como palavra ou não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Correções:

- Inclusão dos cabeçalhos `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h` e `string.h`
- `ssize_t` -> `size_t`
- Remoção de `exit_on_null`
- `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; /` -> `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';`
- E muitas outras

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int palavras(char *line)
{
  int p = 0;
  char *delim = " \t\r\n\v\f";

  char *str = strtok(line, delim);
  for (; str != NULL; ++p)
    str = strtok(NULL, delim);

  return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  FILE * fp;
  size_t n = 0;

  int nlinhas = 0, p = 0;
  char * line = NULL;

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  while ((n = getline(&line, &n, fp)) != -1)
  {
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';

    p = p + palavras(line);
    nlinhas++;
  }

  printf("Número de Linhas: %i\n",nlinhas);
  printf("Número de Palavras: %i\n",p);

  if (line)
    free(line);

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Posso estar enganado, mas `getline` e `strtok_r` não fazem parte da biblioteca padrão C então de certa forma é melhor evitar. 

São tantas correções que não vale a pena explicar uma por uma.

#### Explicação

```
1|  // ...
2|  char *str = strtok(line, delim);
3|  for (; str != NULL; ++p)
4|    str = strtok(NULL, delim);
5|  // ...
```

`Linha 2`: Chama `strtok` para obter a string até algum caracter de `delim`.
`Linha 3`: A primeira parte do `for` é ignorada. Na condição do `for`, testa se `str` não é `NULL`, `strtok` retorna `NULL` quando não acha o caracter(no caso alguém de `delim`). Na terceira parte é onde as palavras são contadas quando incrementa `p`. 
`Linha 4`: pega a próxima string até alguém de `delim`, caso `delim` não seja achado `strtok` retorna `NULL` fazendo o loop parar.

Comment: Gostei muito da sua solução será que me podia explicar melhor o ciclo for por favor? obrigado

Comment: Qual ciclo? de contagem de palavras?

Comment: Sim esse mesmo.

Comment: edite a resposta com a explicação